# SQLCMD :!! Dir producing no output

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

I fire up SQLCMD at the cmd prompt on Windows 7:

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
1> :!! dir
2> go
1> quit
```

But I see no output on the console.  Figure its a rookie mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, consider to mark it as such one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near as I can tell the utility just has a bug.  Watching it with process explorer shows that when attempting to run a command it creates an invalid path to cmd.exe by appending "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" to whatever the working directory is.

So if you execute sqlcmd from `C:\` it will try and run `C:\"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"` which fails due to being a invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you input a command manually in the mysqlcmd you need to follow a row with go so it will detect the end of the command and the execution will be started. likely with that you will get an error.

Comment: tried that, no joy.  I updated the original post to show my work and results

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` runs under account that has no permissions to read a content of system drive ?

Otherwise you would see, something similar to:

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is A866-F891

 Directory of 

08-Feb-19  09:30    <DIR>          .
08-Feb-19  09:30    <DIR>          ..
15-Sep-18  10:06    <DIR>          0409
23-Aug-16  14:12            21,007 07010000000000000000000000000000.tlbin
17-Jan-19  09:55    <DIR>          1033
15-Sep-18  08:29             2,151 12520437.cpx
15-Sep-18  08:29             2,233 12520850.cpx
15-Sep-18  08:29               232 @AppHelpToast.png
...
```

Comment: I'm running as local admin

Comment: LocalDB always runs under the users security context; that is, **LocalDB never runs with credentials from the local Administrator's group.**  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That's fine.  My users account is in the Windows System Administrators group.  Also, I get the same results on any folder, even c:\temp

Comment: Documentation says that LocalDB omit admin permissions, so even if your account is local admin, LocalDB does not use that. Another statement from documentation, perhaps it will make it more clear - **This means that all database files used by a LocalDB instance must be accessible using the owning user's Windows account, without considering membership in the local Administrators group.**. So it means, that LocalDB cannot leverare admin permissions to access a filesystem and I believe this is a reason of a  behavior of SQLCMD that you observe

Comment: I think you may be thinking about this incorrectly.  IIUC, when you use the :!! command, SQLCMD just passes that to the shell in the same context in which it was invoked.

Comment: FWIW I get the same results when not connected to any database, or when connected to a remote database where the account has admin privs on the server and SQL

Comment: I think you are right, but as the last resort, can you try to run CMD.exe as admin and try once more?

Comment: No change.  Still no output. Funnily enough, using SSMS works, but SQLCMD not so much

Comment: Works in SSMS, fails in SQLCMD

Comment: I think Kicken gave a correct answer. Perhaps this issue is already fixed in newer versions of client tool, that is why it is not always reproducible.